# inner join function with params

Tags: sql, t-sql, function

Is it possible to do this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM xcu
  JOIN fun_Blocked_Dates('2011-01-01', '2012-01-01', xcu.uid) bd ON bd.uid = xcu.uid
```

It seems that function Blocked_Dates is unable to accept xcu.uid as a valid parameter.

I get an error "Incorrect syntax near 'xcu'."

Comment: TSQL is used by both Sybase and SQL Server -- which are you using, and what version?  Might help to see the function code too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM xcu
  CROSS APPLY fun_Blocked_Dates('2011-01-01', '2012-01-01', xcu.uid)
```

You can't use fields from tables as parameters to a function in a join. You need to use cross apply.

Comment: What if I want to use

    SELECT * FROM xcu
    where uid not in (select distinct uid from fun_Blocked_Dates('2011-01-01', '2012-01-01', xcu.uid))

How to avoid xcu.uid error? Should I use cross apply again and then reuse xcu.uid as a parameter?

Thanks

Comment: @John – I have a hard time understanding what you really want to query. You have uid as a parameter to a function. That function will return rows with different uid's including the one that is passed to the function and you don't want the rows from xcu where the rows from function fun_Blocked_Dates have a uid with the same value as you provided as a parameter? When using CROSS APPLY you should think of it as every row in xcu will be used to execute the function. So if you have 3 rows in xcu the function will be executed 3 times with 3 different xcu.uid as parameters.

Comment: Try this. select *
from xcu
where uid not in
   (select distinct bd.uid
    from (select xcu.uid) as t(u) 
      cross apply fun_Blocked_Dates('2011-01-01', '2012-01-01', t.u) as bd)

Comment: Could you explain me what is t(u)? I get Incorrect syntax near 't'. I appreciate your help

Comment: I want to retrieve all the uid's from xcu that are not in fun_Blocked_Dates (this function returns list of uid based on dates passed). I used uid as a param in this function because I want to filter/decrease dataset returned and improve the performance. Param is passed as xcu.uid.

Comment: @John - `t(u)` is a table and column alias in the sub query. I don't know why you get a syntax error. I have not tested the code since I don't have your tables or UDF. If you want performance to improve you should probably not use the function at all and instead try to include what the function does in your query directly.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is [Cross Apply](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/nakul/archive/2011/04/28/cross-apply-underappreciated-features-of-microsoft-sql-server.aspx)